# Prove that (L∞,∥⋅∥∞) is non-separable.

Tags: real-analysis

Define the essential supremum of a function $f\in L_\infty$ by
$\|f\|_\infty:=\inf_{A\subseteq [0,1], \\m(A)=0}\sup_{x\in [0,1]\setminus A}|f(x)|.$

show that $(L_\infty, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is non-separable.
I know how to prove l∞ is not separable，but I don`t know how to structure a uncountable subset on L∞,please help me,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the elements $I_{(x,x+\frac 1 2)}$ with $0<x<\frac 1 2$. Verify that you get uncountably many elements at distance $1$ from each other.

Suppose $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ is  a collection of elements of a metric space such that $d(x_i,x_j)\geq r>0$ whenever $i \neq j$. Suppose the metric space is separable. Let $\{y_1,y_2,...\}$ be  a countable dense set. For each $i \in I$ pick $y_{n(i)}$ in $B(x_i,r/2)$. Consider the map $i \in I \to n(i)$. This map is injective because $y_{n(i)}=y_{n(j)}$ implies there is a point in $B(x_i,r/2) \cap B(x_j,r/2)$ which can only happen when $i=j$. [ Use triangle inequality to justify this]. Since there is an injective map from $I$ into $\mathbb N$ it follows that $I$ is countable. In other words, what we have proved is that in  separabel metric space we cannot have uncountably many points separated by a positive distance.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Why this would implies non separability ? (for me separability mean that there is a countable dense subset)

Comment: A dense set has members with distance less than $1/2$ from each of those $I_{(x,x+\frac 1 2)}$.

Comment: Consider open balls of radius $1/2$around these functions. If there is a countable dense set pick an element of this countable set from each ball and consider the map which takes the ball to the element you have picked. Can you see a contradiction?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Not really...

Comment: @user657324 I have added details to my proof.